# Loading JSON failed after adding localization to it Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift3

Hey I have an JSON for preset Data in my App. Normally I loaded the data like this:

```
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "document", ofType: "json")

    {

        let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
  ... }
```

but after i have localized the document.json file like this:

[image]

Nothing data won't get loaded. 
Does someone know how to get the localized data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the localization the localized files are in the `lproj` folders rather than  in the mein `Resources` folder.

A solution is to create an array with the supported languages and get the current language from the current locale. If the current language does not match one of the supported languages, fall back to the default language.

```
let supportedLocalizations = ["en", "de"]

let currentLanguage : String
if let locale = Locale.current.languageCode, supportedLocalizations.contains(locale) {
    currentLanguage = locale
} else {
    currentLanguage = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion") as! String
}
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document", withExtension: "json", subdirectory: nil, localization: currentLanguage)!
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
```

If the forced unwrapped parts were crashing they reveal a design error. All files are supposed to exist at runtime.